# iOS : detecting finger leaving the screen on the sides ?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

Is there a method/class to detect if the finger leaves the screen when sliding out the screen on one of the sides ?

Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using touchesEnded to detect where the finger was when the touch ended.  If it is at the edge of the screen side, it can be inferred that the user has left the screen.

So on an iPhone, if it is the left or right side, it would have an x coordinate of 0 or 320, and if it was the top and bottom side, it would have a y coordinate of 0 or 480.
On an iPad it would be 0 and 768, and 0 and 1024 respectively.

```
-(void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

You can start with touchesBegan and detect which direction they were coming from to decide in which direction to slide the screen.

```
-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

touchesBegan and touchesEnded are methods of the UIResponder class, so it should be freely available to use anywhere.